# Concatenate suffix to a twig method

Tags: symfony, macros, twig

I have a **method in class**, which the **last two characters** returns a value or another. The methods are:

*getLastnameAD, getLastnameIN getLastanemBB*

I want to **use a macro** to pass two characters to get the value, more or less as follows.

```
{% macro getLastName (obj, suff) %}
    <span>Lastname: {{ obj.getLastname ~ suff }}</span>
{% endmacro %}
```

But I get the following error;

```
Method "getLastname" for object ... does not exist in ...
```

Do you know if do this **is possible**? If it is not possible. Is there **any solution**?

#### I can not edit the object and the method that generate it, so, i have to get it in the view because it is the only place where I can handle data.

**Greetings and thank you.**

Comment: You can not concatenate method name in object. But, you can create a custom twig function for call to you method: `<span>Lastname: {{ call_to_function(obj, 'getLastName' ~ suff)</span>`

Comment: I think you can use attribute like `{{ attribute(obj, 'getLastname' ~ suff) }}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error that you showed is because Twig is trying to execute the `getLastname()` method in your object and it's not defined.

The solution is the one provided by @qooplmao in a previous comment and use the [attribute() function](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/attribute.html):

```
{{ attribute(obj, 'getLastname' ~ suff) }}
```